# How to pass a certificate as a variable in values.yaml of helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

This is the certificate that needs to be passed as a string.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Variable in helm chart is

```
global:
  dbvalues:
    dbcacertificate:
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a way to pass the certificate which worked.

```
global:
 dbvalues:
   dbcacertificate: |
          -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
          MIICyTCCAbTCEF+F3G/7tLCJj9mZ/RiaPQEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwIzEhMB8G
          A1UEAxMYc2FjLWh2bTAwODc5LnN3aW5mcmEubmV0MB4XDTE5MDkyMDEwMDk1NloX
          DTQ0MDkxMzEwMDk1NlowIzEhMB8GA1UEAxMYc2FjLWh2bTAwODc5LnN3aW5mcmEu
          bmV0MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAtmBCXjv7/8pjzUyq
          O52/NAVgOpVAj+i4d1bMdFvfonUzZVzvTfmTxLoHVXAAYrivYq5Y9hpTVIxM0rWj
          AsomYfH3AEgGYax8YGSdF0LW0USEeXZiaMf+Z5+N43d8BoCdGOkPZZQEIMaQwnxM
          ouLisTV113x0vzHZR7b1JzZyMF5zYw88Lsul+TEOfkpY0zjmoptFM26pYSkx8J87
          n0aTe1ZN7TFDZ3zu629BHYfcwvy2F/m0E6rnFRa7o4o6qXJSfZIe1kqqvbRc
          -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution for this problem was to base64 encode the value, and afterwards decode it in the chart.

Answer (score 1):

You can store a certificate in `config map` or in `secret` and pass it further.

You can create `secret` and store value in it and use it as env variable or else you can save the value in `values.yaml` and point it in helm chart.

Comment: Can you pls. share an example.